# how to suppress linefeed in awk

Tags: awk

While I am conding some `awk` script below, but it generates many unwanted `LF`s. I wonder how to suppress (control) the output of `LF` in this script. Thanks in advance for your kind advice.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    nf=NF
    s=0 # initialization
        if($1==3){print "1,"; s+=50}else{print "0,"}
        if($2==1){print "1,"; s+=50}else{print "0,"}
        print s
        print ","
}END{}' file
```

The content of the file (file) is something like,

```
3,1
3,2
```

In this case, the output is like

```
1,
1,
100
,
1,
0,
50
,
```

That is very clumsy. My desired output is like,

```
1,1,100
1,0,50
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat input 
3,1
3,2

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{c1=c2=sum=0;}$1==3{c1=1;sum+=50}$2==1{c2=1;sum+=50}{print c1,c2,sum}' input 
1,1,100
1,0,50
```

Better Readable:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
       FS=OFS=","
     }
     {
        c1=c2=sum=0;          # reset variables
     }
     $1==3{                   # if col1 equal to 3 then
        c1=1;
        sum+=50
     }
    $2==1{                    # if col2 equal to 1 then
       c2=1;
       sum+=50
    }
    {
        print c1,c2,sum       # print variables 
    }' input
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, fixing OP's attempt here. Corrected and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
   s=0
   if($1==3){s+=50;$1="1"} else{$1="0"}
   if($2==1){s+=50;$1="1"} else{$2="0"}
   print $0,s
}' Input_file
```

***Fixes in OP's attempts:***

- Removed `nf` variable its not needed.
- We need NOT to print asap a condition gets satisfied that's why problem is coming in output, rather we can save values into the fields(eg--> 1st and 2nd fields) and print line at last with variable.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                      ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
    FS=OFS=","                              ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here.
}
{
   s=0                                      ##Setting s as 0 here.
   if($1==3){s+=50;$1="1"} else{$1="0"}     ##Checking if 1st field is 3 then add 50 to s and set 1 to $1 else keep $1 as 0 here.
   if($2==1){s+=50;$1="1"} else{$2="0"}     ##Checking if 2nd field is 3 then add 50 to s and set 1 to $2 else keep $2 as 0 here.
   print $0,s                               ##Printing line and value of s here.
}' Input_file                               ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 
  '3,1
   3,2' |
```

---

```
awk 'BEGIN {__=++_+_;FS=OFS="," }($++NF=50*(($__=!--$__)+($_=_==$_-__)))^!_'
```

---

```
1,1,100
1,0,50
```

Answer (score 0):

You might tell `AWK` to not put newline after each `print` by setting `ORS` to `""`, but then you need to put newline yourself where needed. Your code might be reworked following way:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    ORS="";FS=OFS=","
}
{
    nf=NF
    s=0 # initialization
        if($1==3){print "1,"; s+=50}else{print "0,"}
        if($2==1){print "1,"; s+=50}else{print "0,"}
        print s
        print "\n"
}END{}' file
```

then for `file` content being

```
3,1
3,2
```

it will output:

```
1,1,100
1,0,50
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*